# Some times data is not populating into view (ngFor) through array push in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-changedetection

I have a simple data which I am populating through ngFor into view. I am getting all the objects and pushing into array and then from there I am populating into html.Here its working fine.But in my project the scenario is like I need to get into this page by selecting a event from a previous page.When I am frequently going and selecting events and coming to this page, some cases my data pushing into array but not populating into view.Is there any solution for this.Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<div>
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let x of groupList">
  <td ><span>{{x.vehicle_number}}</span></td>
  <td ><span>{{x.vehicle_name}}</span></td>
  <td ><span>{{x.status}}</span></td> 
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

### home.component.html

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from './../pipes/currency.pipe';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
imageSource :any;
statusdata1: any;
moreThanTen:boolean = false;
showit:boolean = false;
groupList:any = [];
constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    /* First data */
    let response = 
    {"vehicle_number":1,"vehicle_name":"car","status":"yellow"}
    let response1 = {"vehicle_number":0,"vehicle_name":"car","status":"yellow"}
    let response2 = {"vehicle_number":2,"vehicle_name":"car","status":"yellow"}
    this.groupList.push(response,response1,response2);
    console.log(this.groupList);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to implement `onPush` or `ChangeDetectionStrategy` in your component

Doing this will instruct Angular to run change detection on these components and their sub-tree only when new references are passed to them versus when data is simply mutated.

Run `this.ref.markForCheck()` or `this.ref.detectChanges()` when you update your variable and want it to reflect in html

Please check the following links for more information

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/

Comment: I am getting this error 'cannot find changedetectionstrategy' Where to use in my code can you give some example

Comment: please check the second link, it contains a good example, follow it